# FAQs about extensions on Chrome

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzECW.jpg)

Hi everyone, I'm learning about Chrome extensions myself. However, at this point, I do not fully understand. Where I mark in the image is I will have to declare in the manifest.json file or create a new file and in what file format will it be saved?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Add your own efforts such as coding approaches and docs research.

Comment: The thing in the image is the internal code of the extension API, you don't need it. You need to use a text editor or IDE to create and edit files like manifest.json. Start with a tutorial or documentation or find a video tutorial.